# How to launch Console from inside a NUnit test

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, moq

I am running a NUnit testing. I need to launch Console to write test to it. 
When I write in my [Test]

```
Console.Write("test");
```

It doesn't work. I know we are not suppose to be running console or have human interaction. But I have situation where I need display message on Console. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the ReSharper test runner, if you need to see what is displayed on the console, the Console output should be displayed. To do that, click the "Show Output" button in the test runner toolbar:

[image]

Then, you will be able to see the output like this:

[image]

Or, if you use the NUnit GUI runner, there is a "Text output" tab which should show you what you need.

Or, of course, you could use Debug.WriteLine instead to output to VS's "output" box.